# Selenium Webdriver Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a query on mouseover action in Selenium Webdriver Java.

Consider i have a background image with id "Lfade" with opacity 0.5. If i hover the mouse then a button would be shown.

I want to click on the button to take me to another screen. How do i do this ???

I have tried this, but it does not work

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
WebElement tagElement = driver.findElement(By.id("Lfade"));
builder.moveToElement(tagElement).build().perform();
```

**Html**

```
div id="homeslant"
div id="wrapper"
div id="lFade" class="learn" style="opacity: 0.5; visibility: visible;"
```

**Button**

```
div class="descbtn"
a class="btn dwmbutton" href="/learn/index.html">KNOW MORE</a>
```

Comment: Please help for the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46469179/how-to-omit-hidden-options-from-dropdown-using-selenium

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about what you are trying to do but I notice an error here:

```
builder.moveToElement(tagElement).build().perform();
```

Actually, the `.perform()` includes a `.build()`.

May be you were referring to `.click()` so

```
builder.moveToElement(tagElement).click().perform()
```

As a pattern for your objective I would:

- find the first image
- move to the image
- wait
- find the button
- click the button

Comment: It is like Mac dock. Dock would be hidden and when mouse is pointed near dock area the dock area would appear. Similarly in my case the button would appear only when user moves the mouse to that image. As you move the mouse to that image the button would appear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move to the button and perform a click.

1. Move to the image
2. wait
3. Move to the button and click

   Actions act = new Actions(driver);
   WebElement tagElement = driver.findElement(By.id("Lfade"));
   act.moveToElement(tagElement).click().build().perform(); 
   WebElement _button= driver.findElement(By...);
   act.moveToElement(_button).click().build().perform();

Answer (score 0):

I used Robot class for mouse hover.  Please try the below code.

`Robot robot = new Robot();
        Point MyPoint = tagElement.getLocation();
robot.mouseMove(MyPoint.getX(), MyPoint.getY())`;

After that use the normal selenium click to click on the button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='chromemenu']/span/a") WebElement menuHoverLink;
@FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='dropmenu1']/a[1]") WebElement subLink;
Actions maction = new Actions(driver);
maction.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).build().perform();
Thread.sleep(2000);
subLink.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will work :

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
WebElement tagElement = driver.findElement(By.id("Lfade"));
WebElement buttonElement = driver.findElement(By.classname("btn"));
builder.moveToElement(tagElement).moveToElement(buttonElement).click().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void HoverAndClickObject(WebDriver driver, String property1, String property2, String path) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException
        {
            //get object properties from the xml file repository
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            String[] element1 = xmlParser(path, property1);
            String[] element2 = xmlParser(path, property2);
            switch (element1[0].toUpperCase())
              {
                  case "XPATH":
                      driver.findElement(By.xpath(element1[1])).click();    
                      action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath(element2[1]))).click().build().perform();
                      break;

                  case "ID":
                      driver.findElement(By.id(element1[1])).click();
                      break;

                  case "NAME":
                      driver.findElement(By.name(element1[1])).click(); 
                      break;

                  case "LINKTEXT":
                      driver.findElement(By.linkText(element1[1])).click();
                      break;

                  case "CSSSELECTOR":
                      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(element1[1])).click();
                      break;

              }


        }
```