# How to omit hidden options from Dropdown using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, dropdown

If we use the selenium code

```
 Select sel = new Select(ele);
 eles = sel.getOptions();
```

it will returns all element of dropdown options and we can get the value.
But if some options of dropdown are in hidden state and if we use the same Select.getOptions(), it will return the all options including the hidden options.

Code:

```
 <select id="userType" >
       <option value="administrator">Administrator</option>
       <option value="instructor">Instructor</option>
       <option class="studenthide" value="student" style="display: none;">Student</option>
 </select>
```

From the about code, Administrator and Instructor only displayed in dropdown, but Student is not displayed in dropdown.

So how can we get only the displayed options from the drop-down?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to get using select class. But you can get all the visible elements into a list using below xpath

```
 driver.findElements(by.xpath("//select[@id="userType"]/option[not(contains(@style,"display: none"))]"))
```

Comment: Code looks good for standalone programs, but its not suitable for large scale projects.

Comment: I am not sure how large scale is your project. But we can use one or two complex xpath and it won't make any significant difference in execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the alternative snippet:

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//select/option[not(contains(@style,'display: none'))]"));
    for(WebElement element : elements){
        System.out.println(element.getText());
    }
```

Comment: By looking, it works clear. But if i use _isDisplayed()_ on the Xpath, it returns true and actually it is not displaying. And if i use these type of Xpath's in my project, its wothless of using selenium. Any conclusion for my point?

Comment: And we can't assure that there is only one code '@style='display: none'' to hide the options. I'm sure there are many codes available to hide the options in markup languages.

Comment: @DINESHKUMAR : from the code snippet you have given,this is the only thing which differentiates student option from other options. I have used not(contains(@style,"display: none")) in my project multiple times and it works perfectly fine